# Android dark theme doesn't set windowBackground

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a theme that works but refuses to set android:windowBackgorund and android:colorBackground.
The rest of the code works properly, and if I switch the items in the default theme it works properly.

styles.xml:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/radioLight</item>
</style>

<style name="Dark" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/grey</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/grey</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/soft_grey</item>
    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/radioDark</item>
</style>
```

Main:

```
setTheme(R.style.Dark);
```

Don't know if it's useless
activity_main xml:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

What's the shameful mistake i committed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:windowBackground` only accepts a drawable. Try changing it to something like

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/abc</item>
```

And create a file `abc.xml` such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/grey"/>
</shape>
```

And just checking, do you call setTheme before calling `super.onCreate()`?

Comment: The problem was I call the set theme before the super.onCreate() function and the @drawable. thank you so mutch!

Comment: This answer is incorrect. windowBackground does accept a color as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add 2 new resource files:
   For light theme **splash_background.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

for dark theme **splash_background.xml** place it in drawable-night folder (create if you dont have it ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/grey" />
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

2. Finally In your themes.xml:

```
    <style name="Theme.AppName.SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppName">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
    </style>
```